# Sourcetree does not push to github

Tags: github, sourcetree

I have a problem that my repository is not pushed to github.
My repository is located on my pc and I committed it with SourceTree and want to push it upwards to github.

The output says this:

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v
>   --tags --set-upstream ots master:master POST git-receive-pack (chunked)

And processbar keeps moving and moving and moving but nothing happens.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this issue. A timeout appeared after several minutes. I tried to increase the https package size but this didn't help either.

Then I realized what I changed recently: I added several nuget-packages. The package folder had a size of 140MB and was not excluded by .gitignore. I added this to the .gitignore and pushing was working again.